# Computing only the $k$ biggest eigenvalues and eigenvectors with Scalapack

Tags: eigenvalues, fortran, clustering, scalapack

Given that there are eigensolvers in Scalapack that use a divide and conquer method, is there any way we can use Scalapack functions to only compute the first $k$ dominant eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors?

This is for a spectral clustering code.

Comment: (assuming your matrix is sparse/structured and $k$ is small relative to the size of the matrix,) that's exactly what Arnoldi eigenvalue methods (and [ARPACK](http://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK/)) are useful for. a search on this website should produce a number of useful posts on this topic

Comment: Yes , I know about Arnoldi methods , the idea was to do a parallel computation with MPI (hence Scalapack )

Comment: the authors of ARPACK have written a parallel implementation (on top of BLACS and MPI). you can download it from [here](http://www.caam.rice.edu/~kristyn/parpack_home.html)

Comment: Is your matrix symmetric/Hermitian? If so you might look at pdsyevr or pdsyevx (or equivalents if not using doubles)

Comment: @GoHokies please, consider converting two of your very accurate comments into the answers.